# Should hat farming be allowed?

Tags: discussion

We have already had some instances of hat farming, such as:

- [This deleted post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5572/599)
- [This conversation in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12668450#12668450)

So far it's pretty harmless, sometimes even constructive (many suggested edits), but how far should this be allowed to go?

Comment: What is hat farming?

Comment: @ideasman42 Creating questions, starring chats, etc. entirely for the purpose of getting hats.

Comment: this is some of the saddest stuff I have seen in a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously ***not***. I see nothing wrong with obtaining the simpler ones or those available through chat as stars can easily be cancelled and trivial stuff is always starred anyways but I would strongly discourage anyone from hat farming on the main site and disrupting the normal flow of things. We've seen one such instance already so let this be a warning to anyone thinking of doing this.

As such the normal site rules still apply, so anyone caught abusing their site privileges to close/delete questions, push trivial edits or farm reputation will be in violation of this.

Comment: How about going back and finding posts in need of legitimate editing to fix more substantial things (formatting, really bad grammar, adding relevant tags, etc.)? Would this be called "disrupting the flow of the site", or would this be constructive?

Comment: @Keavon Of course not, definitely constructive. I mean mostly people who have the privilege to edit and use this to make one line changes etc. These edited questions are pushed back to the front page and can hide newer posts that need the attention.

Answer (score 7):

In the [FAQ](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/faq) it says

> All normal site rules still apply. If you get suspended, you're disqualified from hats for the duration of your suspension. If you're caught sockpuppeting for hats, you will be suspended, just as you would be normally.

So questions like "Dont look at this" that are just for getting hats should not be
ok but hat collecting like that link to the chat are fine as they don't greatly affect anyone.

And as you said increased edits are a good thing.

Comment: Oh, oops. Sorry. Didn't know that was a rule. I agree that my creating then deletion of that post wasn't constructive, but I share the opinion that many of the hat activities is beneficial to the community such as improving questions through edits. I'll make sure my future hat farming is purely beneficial to the site.